# Constrain digits postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to constrain a number such that it has strictly 8 digits.... no more and no less. There are leading zeros if the number is less than 8 digits long.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT digit_chk CHECK (mynum ~ '[0-9]{8}');
```

However, using the above syntax, there is no error generated when I insert a number with 9 digits:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mynum) VALUES ('123456789');
```

Why?

I should note that there is an error generated when I insert less than 8 digits.

Comment: Does it suffice to have a numeric column with ` (mynum >=10000000 AND mynum <= 99999999)`?

Comment: No. Because the number must have leading zeros.

Comment: Padding leading zeros is typically a presentation function. But perhaps not in your case.

Comment: You need to enclose the regular expression with a `^` and a `$` like so: `'^[0-9]{8}$'`. But you shouldn't really use a regex here. Just use `integer` for the type and a `mynum BETWEEN 0 AND 99999999` constraint on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT digit_chk CHECK (mynum ~ '^[0-9]{8}$');
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> Unlike LIKE patterns, a regular expression is allowed to match anywhere within a string, unless the regular expression is explicitly anchored to the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Thanks Klin! Is there a "LIKE pattern" that would achieve the same thing without me having to anchor the regular expression?

Comment: No, you cannot do this with `like`.